Angular Library not exporting 3rd Party Types
I wrote a typescript library that I've used successfully in several projects.  It includes several types.
I have now written an Angular library that consumes the above typescript library.  I would like to export the typescript library types as part of the Angular library, but nothing appears to be working.
I have tried ('type', 'namespace', and 'my-lib' are placeholders for the actual values, used only to illustrate the issue):
export { <type> } from "<my-lib>";
export * from "<my-lib>";
export { default as <type> } from "<my-lib>";
export * as <namespace> from "<my-lib>";

Nothing seems to work. I have tried pretty much every suggestion that I've seen online.
When I install the Angular library that I created, none of the types from 'my-lib' are recognized.
I see the types from the Angular library, but not the 'my-lib' library.
Surely there must be some way to accomplish this.  It would be silly to have to ask a developer to install another package, before using my Angular library.
Edit:  just for laughs, I exported the 'rxjs' library from the 'my-lib' public-api.ts file, using:
export * from 'rxjs';

And of course, that shows up with no issue.  So, obviously it's possible.  That being said, I'm unable to reproduce the same result from 'my-lib'.

So, just added an unused import of 'my-lib' into the public-api.ts, just before the export, and everything works now...
import * as foo from "<my-lib>"
Hopefully, some typescript guru out there could explain why this is the case.  Why would I need the unused import, in order for this to work

Actually, that didn't work.  Apparently, my-lib had already been installed separately, and that was what was used. :(
Seriously, why is this so difficult?  Do I have to copy-and-paste the 'my-lib' types into my consuming library?
Doesn't make for good reusability or experience.  Hey devs, make sure to install this other library, before you install mine. /s  Don't worry about the fact that they might be using different versions....
